# Why does the TypeScript compiler rename my imports?

Tags: typescript

Here's my TypeScript code:

```
import lodash from "lodash"
```

Here's the generated Javascript code:

```
const lodash_1 = require("lodash");
```

Sad face. Why would TypeScript ever do this variable rename? It's unexpected, useless, and breaks some static tooling I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

> It's unexpected, useless

No, it is not useless. It is renamed for a few reasons, one of which is that the same name would cause a conflict e.g.

```
import x from 'asdf';
{
  const x = 123; 
  console.log(x);
}
console.log(x);
```

## More

If you are interested Babel does similar naming :

```
import x from 'asdf';
console.log(x);
```

becomes:

```
var _asdf = _interopRequireDefault(require("asdf"));
console.log(_asdf.default);
```

> and breaks some static tooling I wrote.

Design your static tooling to operate on *TypeScript* and not the generated *JavaScript*

Comment: That's not a reason. There is no conflict, which is very easy to detect. You came up with code with a conflict but my code has no conflict, so why rename? It is renaming a variable for no reason.